# How to export text into pdf in Java, Android?

Tags: java, android, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create pdf files on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521097/how-to-create-pdf-files-on-android)

I need to create app for exporting text into pdf file. But I don't know how to do it, because I never used it ever. Help me please, give me an example for this task or link for tutorial.

Comment: I tried to use pdfbox, but this library is very big.

Comment: PDFBox and iText are big because PDF is big. For working with iText, buying [iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/) is pretty much a must.

Answer (score 3):

Some libraries in java to acheive this

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

http://itextpdf.com/