# Creating PDF File on Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create pdf files on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521097/how-to-create-pdf-files-on-android)

I have a program that asks the user for information, then I need to put this information on a document/contract. I think I would like to create a pdf file with that information using itext (other alternate ways would also be appreciated). Although, I found that the itext version is not built (at least the free version) for android. My only solution is to create a server, send this information to a server that creates the pdf and then sends the pdf back to my phone. I have no idea how to do this. Or if anyone knows how to make an itext version for android.

Comment: And a second charity upvote because you're new. Just make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Search your problem well before reaching out. 
If you want to do this on the server you can create a simple PHP script that generates the PDF for you.

Just Google for PHP generate PDF and it will give you a lot of links. 
If you want to do the pdf generation on the device you can leverage a java library that does it for you. try this stackoverflow link [create pdf files on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521097/how-to-create-pdf-files-on-android)

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: thanks,noted, will keep in mind